# Fetching data from sqllite dynamically in table layout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, layout-inflater

I am trying to fetch data dynamically from sqllite using table layout. I have used `getLayoutInflater()` for inflating but is not working and unable to get data in table rows.

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.datab;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView user_tv,pass_tv; View view;
TableLayout tb;int counter=0;
TableRow tr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layoutt);
         tb=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);

        //tr=(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);

        SQLiteDatabase md=openOrCreateDatabase("databa",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        md.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (Username varchar(20),Password varchar(20))");
        md.execSQL("INSERT INTO data VALUES('nobal','Sharma')");

    Cursor cr=md.rawQuery("select * from data", null);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        //String username=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Username"));
        if (cr.moveToFirst()){
           do{


               String username = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Username"));
              String passwd=cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("Password"));

        TableRow   view=(TableRow)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layoutt,tb, false);//here NPE
        user_tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        pass_tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        user_tv .setText(username );
        pass_tv.setText(passwd);
       tb.addView(view);//and NPE here

           }while(cr.moveToNext());

        }cr.close();

    }
}
```

And below is layoutt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

logcat is not showing up NOW,but i do tested ,the code gives null pointer exception on the commented lines in the code

Here is Logcat:

```
07-30 01:47:35.219: D/AndroidRuntime(973): Shutting down VM
07-30 01:47:35.219: W/dalvikvm(973): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.datab/com.example.datab.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TableRow
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at com.example.datab.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
07-30 01:47:35.238: E/AndroidRuntime(973):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: can u post logcat? is data fetching success? any errors?

Comment: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/01/android-loading-sqlite-data-tablelayout.html

Answer (score 0):

I feel the approach taken by you can be made better.
You can at all not use a tablelayout, and still get the feel of using a table layout.

A simple approach, your tablerow is nothing but a simple row, and similar rows make a layout, ultimately giving you the look n feel of a tablelayout.
Why not creating a custom linearlayout with two or three textviews inside it with divider views added.

You can inflate this layout in a customadapter class extending BaseAdapter, and in the getView method simply inflate the layout and using a viewholder class you can populate the adapter.